# How to redirect guest user to login page if trying to access upload folder custom plugin WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a created a custom plugin and it has file upload functionality . I want guest user to redirect login page if trying to access upload folder without login.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check if the user is logged in by using `is_user_logged_in()` function, if not then redirect to a login-in page by using [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) function.

```
if(is_user_logged_in()===false){    

    $url = wp_login_url().'/?redirect_to=' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];   
    wp_redirect($url);// it redirects to login page

    exit();
}
```

**Note:** `redirect_to` returns to the same page after successfully logged in where you were.

[`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/): it retruns  (bool) **True** if the user is logged in, **false** if not logged in.

[`wp_login_urn()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/) it returns login url.

Comment: Okay, so put it at the top of the page.

Comment: I have tried this code at plugin main file but it is not working

Comment: sorry I can't share its, but I put this code at the top of the file as you mentioned.
I also have .htaccess code which is working fine but I can't login to site.

Comment: Here is my .htaccess code

# Protect only some files within the uploads folder
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?/?)wp-content/plugins/custom-path/custom-path/.*\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|txt|rtf|html|htm|xlsx?|docx?|mp3|mp4|mov)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Comment: Do you try it with .htaccess file?

Comment: yes, I have tried it with .htaccess file in plugin folder , it is working fine but the issue is I cant login to site.

Comment: @AnoopKumar, I have put the above in template file at the top of the page and it's working fine.

Comment: It may work on template file.I appreciate your help! But the issue is that i am having plugin and there is uploads folder where i have uploaded all the files attached to form so i do not want to access the files directly with url without logging in.

Comment: I think you want to restrict to upload media for not logged in users right? Please put this in htaccess file RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: please see this url https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in

Answer (score 0):

On the pages that has access to upload-features, you could add this code (in the top):

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
  wp_redirect( wp_login_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
  die();
}
```